# Dropdown menu dissappears when moving mouse towards the menu itself

Tags: html, css, menu

Dropdown menu disappears when hovering away from the "Company" link and towards the menu itself.
I'm trying to accomplish a hoverable dropdown menu that is accessible without clicking on the link
I've searched and tried various solutions posted on stack but they haven't worked.

```css
.nav-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    transition: all 0.6s ease;

}

.nav-link:hover + .nav-dropdown {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translate(0px);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #999;
    color: #cf20fb;

}

.nav-dropdown-link a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #567ff4;
}

.nav-dropdown li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-dropdown li:hover, a:hover {
    color: #cf20fb;

}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="logo-container">
        <img src="images/euro_trans.png" alt="logo" width="300" height="75">
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Company<i class="arrow-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                    <li class="nav-dropdown-link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-dropdown-link"><a href="#">Transport</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-dropdown-link"><a href="#">Key Figures</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Business</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Career</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a gap between your link and your dropdown. I used a pseudoelement on the `.nav-link` to fill it so the user has a bit of buffer when mousing down to the dropdown.

Then your dropdown wasn't set to stay visible when it was being hovered over, so I just added `.nav-dropdown:hover` to that set of styles so it stays open as long as the mouse is within its bounds.

```css
.nav-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
    z-index: 2;
}

.nav-link.has-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-link.has-dropdown:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: -30px;
}

.nav-link:hover + .nav-dropdown,
.nav-dropdown:hover {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translate(0px);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #999;
    color: #cf20fb;
}

.nav-dropdown-link a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #567ff4;
}

.nav-dropdown li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-dropdown li:hover, a:hover {
    color: #cf20fb;

}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="logo-container">
        <img src="images/euro_trans.png" alt="logo" width="300" height="75">
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link has-dropdown" href="#">Company<i class="arrow-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                    <li class="nav-dropdown-link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-dropdown-link"><a href="#">Transport</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-dropdown-link"><a href="#">Key Figures</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Business</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Career</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Had to switch .nav-link.has-dropdown:hover:before{}, rest worked like a charm. Much appreciated.